# justify-content-center não está centralizando o conteudo no meu bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

tenho a seguinte estrutura de código

```
<div id="container" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-2">
        <figure id="logomarca">
            <img src="imagens/logomarca.png" alt="logomarca">
        </figure>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Quem somos</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">O que fazemos</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
        <p>dwadwadwa</p>
    </div>
    </div
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade as classes estão funcionando sim, como vc pode ver na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Agora arrumando o código**

Mas só que para fazer o que vc quer vc precisa colocar as classes nas `col-*` e não na `.row`. Além disso, sua `div` da classe `.container-fluid` estava aberta sem fechamento...

Nas `col-*` vc precisa declara primeiro que ela tem `display flex` com a classe `d-flex`, depois vc alinha o conteúdo dentro delas com `align-items-center` e `justify-content-center`

Veja o resultado no código abaixo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <div id="container" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <figure id="logomarca">
                    <img src="imagens/logomarca.png" alt="logomarca">
                </figure>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Quem somos</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">O que fazemos</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contato</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <p>dwadwadwa</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

- Documentação oficial do Flex do Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/
- Documentação oficial do Grid do Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/